# What physical glass lens could be used to simulate gravitational lensing?

Tags: general-relativity, geometric-optics

I'd like to do a demonstration where the angle of deflection on a dot drawn on a paper is calculated similarly to that of and object distorted by gravitational lensing. Would a double-convex lens work as a life-like approximation? Specifically, I want to be able to model the first equation listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lensing_formalism), i.e.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

An ordinary convex lens doesn't work because the deflection is approximately proportional to the impact parameter. You want *inverse* proportionality. That implies something rather peculiar: a convex lens with *negative* curvature!

But, ordinary objects to the rescue: the [base of a wine glass](https://www.ingridscience.ca/node/525) has about the shape you want.

Comment: Awesome thank you!